# Try catch not handling error when API request is empty

Tags: c#, blazor

I am fetching an API that returns a JSON response.

There are times when an empty value is passed instead of a URL in this code:

```cs
try 
{
    HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(WorkItemsListUri).Result;
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    
    ResponseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(); 
    
    JsonResponseContent = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<WorkItemsListModel>(ResponseContent);
}
catch(HttpRequestException e) 
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("CAUGHT EXCEPTION:");
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e);
}
```

When the application loads the first time `WorkItemsListUri` is empty, i.e.

```cs
public string WorkItemsListUri { get; set; } = String.Empty;
```

This property is injected with the URL only after a click is performed.

But when the page loads, the script runs automatically and shows the following page:

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
> InvalidOperationException: An invalid request URI was provided. Either
> the request URI must be an absolute URI or BaseAddress must be set.

I am trying to find a way where the page can be displayed without any issues and the code will display return results when the URL is passed

Comment: If that code runs in async context, as evident from the `await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()`, then why do you have [`GetAsync(WorkItemsListUri).Result`](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html)?

Comment: I don't know that part actually, it was a copy/paste from a tutorial which worked in fetching the API as I wanted it to

Comment: There are two scenarios, when you do not have a valid `WorkItemsListUri` and when you do not have an URL at all (`string.IsNullOrEmpty(WorkItemsListUri)`). If you want to control the second scenario, you should not execute that code at all. It is not "lets control the exception" but it should be "lets not execute that code"

Comment: @Cleptus I would like to use the second one, what is the best way to exit a `using()` loop where this code is located?

Comment: nevermind, it works using `return` thanks @Cleptus and Gserg